# как импортировать свой модуль?

Tags: c++

есть файлы которые лежат в одной папке

`file1.cxx`

```
int f(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

`file2.cxx`

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << f(2, 5);
}
```

как мне в `file2` вызвать функцию из `file1`?

сделал как в ответ от @zhihar, выводить ошибку:

```
/data/user/0/ru.iiec.cxxdroid/cache/iiec_tmp_source_file-cf564f.o: In function `main':
/storage/emulated/0/Python/test/file2.cxx:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `f(int, int)'
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Оба .cxx-файла нужно "добавить в проект". Как именно это сделать - зависит от IDE.

Comment: При компиляции file2 нужно добавить объектный файл file1 для линковки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо каким-то образом *объявить* функцию в `file2.cxx` - например, хотя бы так:

```
#include<iostream>

int f(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << f(2, 5);
}
```

Обычно таких объявлений много, и потому их выносят в отдельный заголовочный файл, которвый включают директивой `#include`.

Только в вашем случае надо собирать в программу ОБА файла - или настроить проект, чтобы в нем были оба файла, или указывать оба в командной строке.

Answer (score 2):

создайте там же файл `file1.h` в котором укажите функции из `file1.cxx`

```
int f(int a, int b);
```

а в `file2.cxx` просто вызовите

```
#include "file1.h"
```

Comment: сделал как вы, появились ошибки, удалил `file1.h` и место `include "file1.h"` написал `#include "file1.cxx"` и все заработало почему так?

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть, чтоб в проекте компилировались и линковались оба файла - для вас это очевидно, но не для спрашивающего...

Comment: @Vlad Инклудить `.cxx`/`.cpp` - зло, не надо так делать. Правильно - создать отдельный `.h`. Лучше покажите ошибки. Кстати, почему `.cxx` а не `.cpp`, первый раз вижу такое расширение...

Comment: в `file1.cxx` вначале надо было написать #include `file.1h`